# compare and filter 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 arrays.  I need to show only data which does not match with the second array.

```
array1 = [
  {
    country: "usa", 
    child: [
      { id: 1, name: "fvsdfsd"   },
      { id: 2, name: "hhghhhfhj" },
    ],
  },
  {
    country: "CA", 
    child: [
      { id: 3, name: "adsada"    },
      { id: 4, name: "hhghhhfhj" },
    ],
  },
  {
    country: "AU",
    child: [
      { id: 5, name: "seven"     },
      { id: 6, name: "hhghhhfhj" },
    ],
  },
];

array2 = [
  { id: 1, name: "fvsdfsd"   },
  { id: 2, name: "hhghhhfhj" },
];
```

result:

```
[
  {
    country: "usa", 
    child: [],
  },
  {
    country: "CA", 
    child: [
     { id: 3, name: "adsada"    },
     { id: 4, name: "hhghhhfhj" },
    ],
  },
  {
    country: "AU",
    child: [
      { id:5, name: "seven"     },
      { id:6, name: "hhghhhfhj" },
    ],
  },
]
```

I try like this but its not working

```
array1.filter(data => !array2.includes(data.child));
```

Comment: FYI your arrays are not valid javascript arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can try like this.

`array1.map(item1 => ({ ...item1, child: item1.child.filter(childItem => !array2.find(item2 => JSON.stringify(item2) === JSON.stringify(childItem))) }));`

If the keys of the object are not in the same order, as Everett Glovier said, you can try like this.

`array1.map(item1 => ({ ...item1, child: item1.child.filter(childItem => !array2.find(item2 => item2.id === childItem.id && item2.name === childItem.name)) }));`

Comment: just a heads up: js keys are not always in the same order, so this can return false.

Comment: There is no guarantee that two seemingly identical (but different) javascript objects will serialize to JSON with properties in the same order.  From MDN's article on [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify): "**Note:** Properties of non-array objects are not guaranteed to be stringified in any particular order. Do not rely on ordering of properties within the same object within the stringification."

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because of how Ecma/Javascript does equality testing. `Array.includes()` uses the [*sameValueZero*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value_equality) algorithm for determining if two things are "equal".

[And equality in Javascript is odd]

Object comparison is done by ***reference***, so two object are equal if (and only if) they are the exact same object in memory. For instance

```
const areEqual = {a:1,b:2} === {a:1,b:2}
```

is `false`, as is

```
const areEqual = {a:1,b:2} == {a:1,b:2}
```

You need to do *deep equality* checking with something like lodash's [`isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual):

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const areEqual = _.isEqual( {a:1,b:2} , {a:1,b:2} ) ; // returns true
```

So you should be able to say something like:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const filtered = array1.map( o => {
  return {
    ...o,
    child: _.isEqual( o.child, array2 ) ? [] : o.child ),
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare two different objects using includes in javascript, because includes uses ===. Only references to the same object will return true using ===. You'll need to write a custom function that runs through all of the keys of your object and compares their values between your two arrays.

This article explains some techniques for comparing two objects:
https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/